# Nouveau crash after resuming from sleep

Tags: debian, x11, nvidia, nouveau

System is Debian 11 Bullseye, upgraded from Debian 10 Buster.

After resuming from sleep, the graphical display is just snow.  The system is still running, but the display is unusable.  The keyboard can be recovered with magic SysRq key, so the system can be shutdown cleanly.  This started to happen directly after upgrading to Debian 11 Bullseye from Buster.

The graphics card is a GeForce 210:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce 210] (rev a2)
```

Nouveau only logs these items:

```
Dec 28 11:49:42 xxx kernel: [52702.105184] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: TRAP_MP_EXEC - TP 0 MP 0: 00000010 [INVALID_OPCODE] at 07fec0 warp 0, opcode fffdb9bf 7f3fdffe
Dec 28 11:49:42 xxx kernel: [52702.105205] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: TRAP_MP_EXEC - TP 0 MP 1: 00000010 [INVALID_OPCODE] at 07fec0 warp 0, opcode fffdb9bf 7f3fdffe
Dec 28 11:49:42 xxx kernel: [52702.105216] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: 00200000 [] ch 9 [003f474000 plasmashell[3671]] subc 3 class 8597 mthd 15f0 data 00940093
```

The question is, what is causing the crash and how to fix it?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani, the older kernel does not have the problem.  Sleep overall is better with the Buster kernel, weird things are going on with the Bullseye kernel.  Do you want that I should compile some kernels to pin it down, Boss, or is this a known problem?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani, if you paste your response into an answer, I will accept it.  The next task is to find a usable .config so that a kernel can be compiled.  So far, no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens every now and then with kernels. I checked and a similar issue [has been reported in Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=989705).

If you're into compiling kernels, you can try the (simple) fix in [message #30](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=989705#30), that is to disable the kernel config option:

```
CONFIG_INIT_ON_ALLOC_DEFAULT_ON
```

Otherwise, unless you need something specific from the newer kernel, you can keep on using the old one until it is fixed. In [message #20](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=989705#20) there is table of working and non-working kernels, if your issue is indeed triggered by the same bug.

If you decide to rebuild the kernel, for Debian you can follow [the official guide](https://kernel-team.pages.debian.net/kernel-handbook/ch-common-tasks.html#s-common-official). The `.config` file for the kernels is in `/boot/config-*`.

Comment: Just so that the answer is not entirely a set of links to another site, the fix in message #30 is to disable the kernel config option, CONFIG_INIT_ON_ALLOC_DEFAULT_ON .

Comment: @casualunixer you're right. Moving from comment to answer it makes sense to add the information there. Done.